# Java replaceAll / replace string with instances of dollar sign

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, dollar-sign

```
public static String template = "$A$B"

public static void somemethod() {
         template.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("$")+"A", "A");
         template.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("$")+"B", "B");
             //throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 3
         template.replaceAll("\\$A", "A");
         template.replaceAll("\\$B", "B");
             //the same behavior

         template.replace("$A", "A");
         template.replace("$B", "B");
             //template is still "$A$B"

}
```

I don't understand. I used all methods of doing the replacement I could find on the internets, including all stack overflow I could found. I even tried \u0024! What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The replacement isn't done inplace (A `String` can't be modified in Java, they are *immutable*), but is saved in a new `String` that is returned by the method. You need to save the returned `String` reference for anything to happen, eg:

```
template = template.replace("$B", "B");
```

Comment: DAMN! I did it like a milion times before in the correct way. I just forgot it! Thanks!

Comment: @emha If you find the answer useful, why don't you accept it?

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable. So you need to assign the return valur of replaceAll to a new String:

```
String s = template.replaceAll("\\$A", "A");
System.out.println(s);
```